# Why do I need to include statement inside `where` inside of quotes in this python-Spark case?

Tags: python, apache-spark, where-clause

I am learning Spark and had the following code:

`shakeWordsDF = (shakespeareDF
                    .select(explode(split(shakespeareDF.word,'[\s]+'))
                    .alias('word'))
                    .where('word'!='')
                    )`

This code did not work because of "condition should be string or column".
However, [the code by this guy](https://clyyuanzi.gitbooks.io/spark-/content/wordcount.html) worked

```
shakeWordsDF = (shakespeareDF
                .select(explode(split(shakespeareDF.word,'[\s]+'))
                .alias('word'))
                .where("word!=''")
                )
```

I understand what the eror says - it needs string. But why doesn't [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.where) have anything on strings? All tutorials I have seen say that it should be

```
.where(x>2)
```

or (if I'm not wrong)

```
.where('columnName'>2)
```

and not
`.where("x>2")`.

I'm really confused.

Comment: *Documentation* says: `where()` is an alias for `filter()`. Now see [`filter()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.filter): **condition** – a **Column** of **types.BooleanType** or a string of SQL expression. Your second example `.where('columnName'>2)` is not present. But the other two exist.

Comment: @Jeon, my bad. Indeed. Thank you for clarification.